# Individual feature evaluator

Tags: machine-learning, classification, weka

I have a question regarding individual feature evaluator in data mining.

Can `OneRAttributeEval, InfoGainAttributeEval, GainRatioAttributeEval, ChiSquaredAttributeEval`
be used on non-binary class classifiers?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, these feature selection techniques can be used in the context of a multiclass classification problem. Usually, if something works for two classes, it would be extendable to handle multiple classes (2 or more). If you briefly look at how these techniques work, you would understand.

OneR basically constructs a single rule for a feature and calculates the classification accuracy, and the feature selection selects the feature that provides the best performance. Using only a single rule to evaluate the usefulness of features in the context of a multiclass problem may not be the best way, but it can be done.

With regards to the other three techniques, the measures - information gain, gain ratio, chi-square measure - used to evaluate the usefulness of features already take into account a weighted score for each class. Therefore, these techniques can be used for selecting features in the context of multiclass classification.

Also, a quick search and I found the following links:

[OneRAttributeEval](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/DATAMINING/OneRAttributeEval)

[InfoGainAttributeEval](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/DATAMINING/InfoGainAttributeEval)

[GainRatioAttributeEval](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/DATAMINING/GainRatioAttributeEval)

[ChiSquaredAttributeEval](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/DATAMINING/ChiSquaredAttributeEval)

It seems to me that you are looking at these exact functions. If you look at each of these links, you should be able to find "Capabilities". Below that, you can find that each of these functions can handle "Nominal class" (in the row "Class"). Nominal is multiclass.